# MySQL query to find data from different column and check online offline

Tags: mysql, database

There a table tb_user_info

```
id || updatedTime
1  ||  2018-09-21 15:15:49
2  ||  2019-01-21 15:15:49
```

and table tb_user

```
id  ||  name
1   ||  Test1
2   ||  Test2
```

and few other tables too.

I would like to join these tables and select id(user), name(user), and get 'Y' if the updatedTime from tb_user_info is updated less than 5 minutes ago for each users in User table.

Right now I made this code.

```
select u.emp_no, u.name, position, d.name as dept_name,
    (select if (ui.updatedTime >= NOW() - INTERVAL 5 minute, 'Y', 'N') as test
     from tb_user u
     inner join tb_user_dept ud
     on u.emp_no = ud.emp_no
     inner join tb_dept d
     on ud.dept_id = d.dept_id
    inner join tb_user_info ui
    on ud.emp_no = ui.emp_no) as connectYN
from tb_user u
inner join tb_user_dept ud
on u.emp_no = ud.emp_no
inner join tb_dept d
on ud.dept_id = d.dept_id
```

I have to change the as connectYn part..

I would like to have the result something like this.

```
id ||  name   || connectYN
 1  ||  Test1  || 'Y'
 2  ||  Test2  || 'N'
 3  ||  Test3  || 'N'
 4  ||  Test4  || 'Y'
```

Comment: What would the desired result look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query does not quite matches your sample data and expected results.

By looking at your query, it looks to me like you do not need a subquery. You could just `JOIN` all tables and put the logic directly in the `SELECT` clause, like.

One thing that is hard to tell without seeing more data is whether you need aggregation or not. Here is a version without aggregation :

```
SELECT 
    u.emp_no, 
    u.name, 
    d.name as dept_name,
    CASE WHEN ui.updatedTime >= NOW() - INTERVAL 5 minute THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END connectYN
FROM 
    tb_user u
    INNER JOIN tb_user_dept ud ON u.emp_no = ud.emp_no
    INNER JOIN tb_dept d       ON ud.dept_id = d.dept_id
    INNER JOIN tb_user_info ui ON ud.emp_no = ui.emp_no
```

Comment: I get syntax error at case()~~ How do i fix this..?

Comment: @BongJaeJeong : typo fixed

Answer (score 0):

By putting the updatedTime in the left join we eliminate early.

The `GROUP BY` ensures there is only one row per user. `MAX(updateTime)` is there to ensure the `sql_mode=ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is still correct:

```
SELECT 
    u.emp_no, 
    u.name, 
    d.name as dept_name,
    IF(ISNULL(MAX(updatedTime)),'N','Y')) connectYN
FROM 
    tb_user u
    INNER JOIN tb_user_dept ud ON u.emp_no = ud.emp_no
    INNER JOIN tb_dept d       ON ud.dept_id = d.dept_id
    LEFT JOIN tb_user_info ui ON ud.emp_no = ui.emp_no
        AND ui.updatedTime >= NOW() - INTERVAL 5 minute
GROUP BY u.emp_no, ud.dept_id
```